# What is this syntax in while loop condition?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

```
while ( (i=t-i%10 ? i/10 : !printf("%d\n",j)) || (i=++j<0?-j:j)<101 );
```

I came across this on codegolf

Please explain the usage of `?` and `:` and why is there no statement following the while loop? As in why is there a `;` after the parenthesis.

Comment: Look up "conditional operator" in your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please explain the usage of `?` and `:`

That's the *conditional operator*. `a ? b : c` evaluates `a` and converts it to a boolean value. Then it evaluates `b` if its true, or `c` if its false, and the overall value of the expression is the result of evaluating `b` or `c`.

So the first sub-expression:

- assigns `t-i%10` to `i`. The result of that expression is the new value of `i`.
- if `i` is not zero, the result of the expression is `i/10`
- otherwise, print `j`, and the result of the expression is zero (since `printf` returns a non-zero count of characters printed, which `!` converts to zero).

Then the second sub-expression, after `||`, is only evaluated if the result of the first expression was zero. I'll leave you to figure out what that does.

> why is there no statement following the while loop?

There's an empty statement, `;`, so the loop body does nothing. All the action happens in the side effects of the conditional expression. This is a common technique when the purpose of the code is to baffle the reader; but please don't do this sort of thing when writing code that anyone you care about might need to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

There is a boolean operation going on inside the parentheses of the while loop:

```
while (boolean);
```

Since the ternary operator is a boolean operator, it's perfectly legal.

So what's this doing?  Looks like modular arithmetic, printing going on over a range up to 101.

I'll agree that it's cryptic and obscure.  It looks more like a code obfuscation runner up.  But it appears to be compilable and runnable.  Did you try it?  What did it do?

Answer (score 3):

The `?:` is a ternary operator.

An expression of form `<A> ? <B> : <C>` evaluates to:

- If `<A>` is true, then it evaluates to `<B>`
- If `<A>` is false, then it evaluates to `<C>`

The `;` after the `while` loop indicates an empty instruction. It is equivalent to writing

`while (<condition>) {}`

The code you posted seems like being obfuscated.

Comment: "Obfuscated": look up "codegolf" in your favourite search engine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Conditional Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx) (also called ternary operator).

It is a one-line syntax to do the same as `if (?)` condition doA `else (:)` doB;

In your example:

```
(i=t-i%10 ? i/10 : !printf("%d\n",j)
```

Is equivalent to

```
if (i=t-i%10)
  i/10;
else
  !printf("%d\n",j);
```

Answer (score 0):

?: is the short hand notation for if then else

```
(i=t-i%10 ? i/10 : !printf("%d\n",j)<br>
```

equals to

```
if( i= t-i%10 )
then { i/10 }
else { !printf("%d\n",j) }
```

Your while loop will run when the statement before the || is true OR the statement after the || is true.

notice that your code does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

while ( (i=t-i%10 ? i/10 : !printf("%d\n",j)) || (i=++j<0?-j:j)<101 );

in the most human-readable i can do it for u, it's equivalent to:

```
while (i < 101)
{
  i = (t - i) % 10;
  if (i > 0)
  {
    i = i / 10;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d\n",j);
  }

  i = ++j;
  if (i < 0)
  {
    i = i - j;
  }
  else
  {
    i = j;
  }
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I am the proud perpetrator of that code. Here goes the full version:

```
main()
{
    int t=getchar()-48,i=100,j=-i;
    while ((i=t-i%10?i/10:!printf("%d\n",j)) || (i=++j<0?-j:j)<101  );
}
```

It is my submission to a programming challenge or "code golf" where you are asked to create the tinniest program that would accept a digit as a parameter and print all the numbers in the range -100 to 100 that include the given digit. Using strings or regular expressions is forbidden.

[Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22975/print-all-numbers-from-100-to-100-which-contain-a-given-digit/23174)'s the link to the challenge.

The point is that it is doing all the work into a single statement that evaluates to a boolean. In fact, this is the result of merging two different while loops into a single one. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
main()
{
  int i,t=getchar()-'0',j=-100;
  do 
  {
      i = j<0? -j : j;
      do
      {
          if (t == i%10) 
          {
             printf("%d\n",j);
             break;
          }
      }
      while(i/=10);
  }
  while (j++<100);       
}
```

Now lets dissect that loop a little.

First, the initialisation.

```
int t=getchar()-48,i=100,j=-i;
```

A character will be read from the standard input. You are supposed to type a number between 0 and 9. 48 is the value for the zero character ('0'), so t will end up holding an integer between 0 and 9.

i and j will be 100 and -100. j will be run from -100 to 100 (inclusive) and i will always hold the absolute value of j.

Now the loop:

```
while ((i=t-i%10?i/10:!printf("%d\n",j)) || (i=++j<0?-j:j)<101  );
```

Let's read it as

```
while ( A || B ) /* do nothing */ ;
```

with A equals to (i=t-i%10?i/10:!printf("%d\n",j)) and B equals to (i=++j<0?-j:j)<101

The point is that A is evaluated as a boolean. If true, B won't be evaluated at all and the loop will execute again. If false, B will be evaluated and in turn, if B is true we'll repeat again and once B is false, the loop will be exited.

So A is the inner loop and B the outer loop. Let's dissect  them

```
(i=t-i%10?i/10:!printf("%d\n",j))
```

It's a ternary operator in the form i = CONDITION? X : Y; It means that first CONDITION will be evaluated. If true, i will be set to the value of X; otherwise i will be set to Y.

Here CONDITION (t-i%10) can be read as t - (i%10). This will evaluate to true if i modulo 10 is different than t, and false if i%10 and t are the same value.

If different, it's equivalent to i = i / 10;
If same, the operation will be i = !printf("%d\n",j)

If you think about it hard enough, you'll see that it's just a loop that checks if any of the decimal digits in the integer in i is equal to t.

The loop will keep going until exhausting all digits of i (i/10 will be zero) or the printf statement is run. Printf returns the number of digits printed, which should always be more than zero, so !printf(...) shall always evaluate to false, also terminating the loop.

Now for the B part (outer loop), it will just increment j until it reaches 101, and set i to the absolute value of j in the way.

---

Hope I made any sense.

Yes, I found this thread by searching for my code in google because I couldn't find the challenge post.